# How to calculate average from nested values in an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the average duration for each stage. So in the array below - I should be able to get the average duration for 'test1', which would be 2.

```
jobs = [
{
    "build_id": 1,
    "stage_executions": [
        {
          "name": "test1"
          "duration": 1,

        },

        {
          "name": "test2"
          "duration": 16408,

        },

        {
          "name": "test3"
          "duration": 16408,

        },
    ]
 },
 {
    "build_id": 2,
    "stage_executions": [
        {
          "name": "test1"
          "duration": 3,

        },

        {
          "name": "test2"
          "duration": 11408,

        },

        {
          "name": "test3"
          "duration": 2408,

        },
    ]
 }
]
```

My failed attempt:

```
avgDuration: function(jobs) {
  let durationSum = 0
  for (let item = 0; item < this.jobs.length; item++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.jobs[item].stage.length; item++) {
      durationSum += stage.duration
    }
    durationAverage = durationSum/this.jobs[item].stage.length
  }
  return durationAverage
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm not sure how to accomplish this since the duration is spread out between each job.

UPDATE:
This is return a single average for all stages rateher than per stage

```
<template>
  <div class="stages">
    <h3>
      Average Duration
    </h3>
    <table>
      <tbody>
          <tr v-for="item in durations">
              <td>
              <b>{{ item.average}} {{ item.count }}</b>
              // this returns only 1 average and 177 count instead of 10 
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { calculateDuration } from "../../helpers/time.js";
import { liveDuration } from "../../helpers/time.js";
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  name: "Stages",
  data() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      durations: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    avgDuration: function(jobs) {
      var averageByName = {}; // looks like { 'name': { average: 111, count: 0 }}
      for (var job of jobs) {
        for(var stage of job.stage_execution) {
              if (averageByName[stage.name] == null) { // we need a new object
                averageByName[stage.name] = { average: 0, count: 0 };
              }
              // just name it so its easier to read
              var averageObj = averageByName[stage.name];
              // update count
              averageObj.count += 1;
              // Cumulative moving average
              averageObj.average = averageObj.average + ( (stage.duration - averageObj.average) / averageObj.count );
              console.log(averageObj.count)
            }
          }
      return averageByName
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.JobExecEndpoint =
      process.env.VUE_APP_TEST_URL +
      "/api/v2/jobs/?limit=10";
    fetch(this.JobExecEndpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
        this.jobs.push({
          name: body[i].job.name,
          job: body[i].job,
          stage_execution: body[i].stage_executions,
        });
      }
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.$emit("loading", true);
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.durations = this.avgDuration(this.jobs);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error Fetching:", this.JobExecEndpoint, err);
        return { failure: this.JobExecEndpoint, reason: err };
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: what do you want with the result?

Comment: im not sure yet - return it or create a new array with just job names and average durations

Comment: do you have always the same length of stages?

Comment: no not always  .

Comment: Noticed in the second `for loop` you're incrementing `item` instead of `i`. I'm guessing that's a typo

Comment: why not to use `.reduce` you could accumulate the amount of occurrences and general duration. By the end you could divide the accumulated duration by the amount of occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this pretty simply and without overflow from having too many numbers by using a **Cumulative moving average** and a few loops.

Here is a line the relevant [Wikipedia page on Moving Averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) and the most relvant formula below.

[image: Moving Average Formula]

I will not go into much detail with the above as there are a lot of documents describing this sort of thing. I will however say that the main reason to this over adding all the values together is that there is a far lower chance of overflow and that is why I am using it for this example.

Here is my solution with comments made in code.

```js
var jobs = [ { "build_id": 1, "stage_executions": [ { "name": "test1", "duration": 1, }, { "name": "test2", "duration": 16408, }, { "name": "test3", "duration": 16408, }, ] }, { "build_id": 2, "stage_executions": [ { "name": "test1", "duration": 3, }, { "name": "test2", "duration": 11408, }, { "name": "test3", "duration": 2408, }, ] } ];

var averageByName = {}; // looks like { 'name': { average: 111, count: 0 }}
for (var job of jobs) {
    for(var stage of job.stage_executions) {
        if (averageByName[stage.name] == null) { // we need a new object
            averageByName[stage.name] = { average: 0, count: 0 };
        }
        // just name it so its easier to read
        var averageObj = averageByName[stage.name];
        // update count
        averageObj.count += 1;
        // Cumulative moving average
        averageObj.average = averageObj.average + ( (stage.duration - averageObj.average) / averageObj.count );
    }
}
// print the averages
for(var name in averageByName) {
    console.log(name, averageByName[name].average);
}
```

**Let me know if you have any questions or if anything is unclear.**

Comment: this solution seems like the easiest for me to follow, but I'm having trouble trying to turn your example into a function

Comment: @benjaminadon what kind of function are you wanting? Maybe the average for a single stage, or would you prefer an object with the averages for all stages?

Comment: I was able to turn it into a working function.  Now I have an issue where it is calculating the average of ALL stages instead of per stage.  I'm sure this is an issue with my jobs data not being structured as I thought.  I will accept your answer though since it put me on the right path and has the working code snippet

Comment: @benjaminadon if you include more information in your post I may be able to help you more. Try posting your current function and I'll take a look at it

Comment: @benjaminadon Please take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/james_wasson/fmku2gz0/. I really only changed the part about loading from the server and it works fine. Are you sure your data is structured the same way?

Comment: the data was NOT structured the same way

Comment: The stage name was nested a little deeper like this "stage_executions": [{"name": {"name": "test"}}]

Comment: Once I noticed that, it was a trivial fix.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to reverse the order of averageByName.  The averages are returning in the opposite order I want them.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the values in an object for each index and map later only the averages.

```js
var jobs = [{ build_id: 1, stage_executions: [{ name: "test1", duration: 1 }, { name: "test2", duration: 16408 }, { name: "test3", duration: 16408 }] }, { build_id: 2, stage_executions: [{ name: "test1", duration: 3 }, { name: "test2", duration: 11408 }, { name: "test3", duration: 2408 }] }],
    averages = jobs
       .reduce((r, { stage_executions }) => {
           stage_executions.forEach(({ duration }, i) => {
               r[i] = r[i] || { sum: 0, count: 0 };
               r[i].sum += duration;
               r[i].avg = r[i].sum / ++r[i].count;
           });
           return r;
       }, []);

console.log(averages.map(({ avg }) => avg));
console.log(averages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten the jobs array into an array of `{name:string,duration:number}` object. Also, to make more solution a bit more dynamic the function takes in a `field` argument which returns the average for that specific field.

```js
 
   const jobs = [
  {
    "build_id": 1,
    "stage_executions": [
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "duration": 1,

      },

      {
        "name": "test2",
        "duration": 16408,

      },

      {
        "name": "test3",
        "duration": 16408,

      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "build_id": 2,
    "stage_executions": [
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "duration": 3,

      },

      {
        "name": "test2",
        "duration": 11408,

      },

      {
        "name": "test3",
        "duration": 2408,

      },
    ]
  }
];

const caller = function(jobs, field) {
  const filtered = jobs
    .flatMap((item) => item.stage_executions)
    .filter(item => {
      return item.name === field;
    })
  const total = filtered.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev + curr.duration;
  }, 0)
  return total / filtered.length;
}

console.log(caller(jobs, 'test1'))
console.log(caller(jobs, 'test2'))
console.log(caller(jobs, 'test3'))
```

In case you get the error `flatMap is not a function`. You can add this code snippet in your polyfill or at the top of your js file.

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda));
};
```

PS: for demostration, I obtained the `flatMap` implementation from [here](https://gist.github.com/samgiles/762ee337dff48623e729)

Comment: Can I move the protoype.flatMap into the function?

Comment: I know what it does but don't really follow how it's being used or where its being called

Comment: Array.flatMap was added in ES2019. Depending on the environment you're running the code, Array.flatMap might not be available. So I just added the implementation in case you run into `flatMap is not a function` error. The code snippet in my answer doesn't need the implementation.